# Negate predicate in remove_if

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I try to remove objects from a vector using vector::erase and std::remove_if. I have an external namespace which does the selection ala:

```
template<unsigned int value, someType collection>
bool Namespace::isValid(const Foo* object){

   do something
}
```

Now I have a vector which contains some element which I want to filter if the are valid. In order to do so I do:

```
 std::vector<foo*> myVector;
 //fill it
 myVector.erase( std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), Namespace::isValid<myValue, myCollectionType>), myVector.end());
```

Now this works fine and removes all valid candidates, but actually I want to keep and remove all other. Hence, I need to negate the predicate. Is there any way to do so? Unfortunately, C++11 is not currently supported in this context.

Thanks

Comment: Use `std::not1<isValid>`

Comment: For the benefit of future readers: `std::not_fn` in C++17.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`std::not1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1) adapter to negate the value returned by your `isValid` function. Note that `std::not1` expects a function *object* (C++ calls this a "functor"), so if you have a plain function in a name space you will also need [`std::ptr_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun) to create a function object out of your function.

So,

```
myVector.erase( std::remove_if( myVector.begin(),
                                myVector.end(),
                                Namespace::isValid<myValue, myCollectionType> ),
                myVector.end() );
```

becomes

```
myVector.erase( std::remove_if( myVector.begin(),
                                myVector.end(),
                                std::not1( std::ptr_fun( Namespace::isValid<myValue, myCollectionType> ) ) ),
                myVector.end() );
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the hint using std::ptr_fun. This finally resolved the remaining compilation errors!

Comment: I think in C++11, you can pass function-pointer also, to `std::not1`. Also, `std::ptr_fun` is **deprecated** in C++11, in preference to `std::mem_fn`. There is also a *similar name* function template called `std::mem_fun` which is also **deprecated**.

Comment: @Nawaz: Right, alas C++11 candy is not useful here since the OP wrote "Unfortunately, C++11 is not currently supported in this context.".

Comment: Right. The code has to run on a grid system which does not provide any recent gcc version. Hence, the only option would have been boost, but std::ptr_fun works just fine.